# Erro X has 2 features per sample; expecting 3147

Tags: python, machine-learning

Estou tentando trabalhar com predições, Machine Learning, mas venho tendo problemas quanto a predição a partir do treino guardado, conforme o erro a seguir:

```
    predict(file_name)
  File "C:/Python/categoriesTest/CategoriaTestFunctions.py", line 129, in predict
    result = loaded_model.predict(X.reshape(1, -1))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 324, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 305, in decision_function
    % (X.shape[1], n_features))
ValueError: X has 2 features per sample; expecting 3147
```

Código que utilizo:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from time import time
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import numpy as np
import re
import string
import sklearn
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="10....", port="5432", database="app", user="app", password="app")


def preprocessor(df):
    df.columns = ['texto', 'cat']
    # print(df) #imprimindo o dataframe
    # Pegando os textos puros da coluna texto, para normalização.
    # textos puros terão de ter um índice
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('-', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('/', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('+', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('ões', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace(';', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('#', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('~', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace(':', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.lower().str.split()
    stop = stopwords.words("portuguese")
    textosPuros = df['texto'].apply(lambda x: [w for w in x if not w in stop])
    return textosPuros


def preprocessorNew(textNew):
    # print(df) #imprimindo o dataframe
    words = textNew.lower().split()
    stop = stopwords.words("portuguese")
    # words = ' '.join([w for w in words if not w in stop])
    return words


def dictionary(texto):
    dicionario = set()
    for lista in texto:
        dicionario.update(lista)
    return dicionario


def defineDictionaryPosition(dicionario):
    totalDePalavras = len(dicionario)
    tuplas = zip(dicionario, np.arange(totalDePalavras))
    tradutor = {palavra: indice for palavra, indice in tuplas}
    print("Total de palavras: ")
    print(totalDePalavras)
    return tradutor


def vectorize_text(text, tradutor):
    vector = [0] * len(tradutor)

    for palavra in text:
        if palavra in tradutor:
            position = tradutor[palavra]
            vector[position] += 1

    return vector


def train(texts, tradutor, marcas):
    print("Training.....")
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,
                                 stop_words='portuguese')
    vetoresDeTexto = [vectorize_text(texto, tradutor) for texto in texts]
    # Define o conjunto de dados X
    X = np.array(vetoresDeTexto)
    # Define o conjunto de dados Y (labels)
    Y = np.array(marcas.tolist())
    # Define porcentagem do treino
    porcentagem_de_treino = 0.8
    # Separa o tamanho do treino a partir da porcentagem
    tamanho_do_treino = int(porcentagem_de_treino * len(Y))
    # O restante fica para a validacao
    tamanho_de_validacao = (len(Y) - tamanho_do_treino)
    # Separa os dados de treino
    treino_dados = X[0:tamanho_do_treino]
    # Separa as marcacoes de treino
    treino_marcacoes = Y[0:tamanho_do_treino]
    # Separa os dados de validacao
    validacao_dados = X[tamanho_do_treino:]
    # Separa as marcacoes de validacao
    validacao_marcacoes = Y[tamanho_do_treino:]
    print("Validacao Marcacoes: ")
    print(validacao_marcacoes)
    clf = LogisticRegression()  # MultinomialNB() obtive 62% de acerto#GaussianNB()
    clf.fit(treino_dados, treino_marcacoes)
    # accuracy
    accuracy = clf.score(validacao_dados, validacao_marcacoes)
    file_name = 'train_data.pkl'
    pickle._dump(clf, open(file_name, 'wb'))
    # fit_file = joblib.dump(clf, file_name)
    print("Indice de acerto do algoritmo: ")
    print("%.2f " % round(accuracy * 100) + "%\n")
    print("End of train...")
    predict(file_name)
    # To get a fit_file
    # return fit_file


# just a test
# HOW??
def predict(fit):
    print("\nPredict......")
    # new text to predict
    new = preprocessorNew('new text')
    X = np.array(new)
    # new_text = preprocessorNew(new)
    # To have the fit file \/
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(fit, 'rb'))
    # how to predict this new data??
    result = loaded_model.predict(X.reshape(1, -1))
    print(result)


df1 = pd.read_sql(
    "SELECT dsobservacaoclinica1, cdcatcategoria AS cat FROM iaconsultas limit 500",
    conn)
df1.columns = ['texto', 'cat']
marca = df1['cat']
textosPuros = preprocessor(df1)
print("Texts...")
print(textosPuros)
dict = dictionary(textosPuros)
print("Dict....")
print(dict)
translate = defineDictionaryPosition(dict)
# to train
train(textosPuros, translate, marca)
# TEST
# predict(textosPuros, translate, marca)
```

Explicando, recebo o retorno da query feita com duas colunas. Cada texto está vinculado a uma categoria, após o treino, tento inserir um novo dado para que este seja predito, ou seja, saber em qual categoria se encaixa. Mas tenho este erro como retorno, como resolver?

Comment: Tem como adicionar alguma amostra dos dados ?

Comment: @DaviMello não entendi sua pergunta. Um anexo com, CSV por exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi a questão alterando a forma de vetorizar os textos de treino e consequentemente, alterei também a forma de vetorizar o texto de entrada.

Antes utilizava a função `vectorize_text` agora utilizo `count_vect = CountVectorizer()` este faz a vetorização dos textos no treino e logo depois utilizo `tvect = TfidfTransformer()` para transformar os textos para o FIT. Isto na função de treino `def train`.

Já função de predição, levo a variável `count_vect` para transformar o texto que gostaria de entrada.

Segue o código abaixo, caso alguém num futuro tenha alguma dúvida parecida:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from time import time
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import numpy as np
import re
import string
import sklearn
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="10....", port="5432", database="app", user="app", password="app")


def preprocessor(df):
    df.columns = ['texto', 'cat']
    # print(df) #imprimindo o dataframe
    # Pegando os textos puros da coluna texto, para normalização.
    # textos puros terão de ter um índice
    # retorno como uma lista de strings para posterior vetorização
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('-', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('/', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('+', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('ões', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace(';', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('#', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace('~', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.replace(':', '')
    df['texto'] = df['texto'].astype(str).str.lower().str.split()
    # uma última limpada no texto, tentando retirar preposições...
    stop = stopwords.words("portuguese")
    textosPuros = df['texto'].apply(lambda x: [w for w in x if not w in stop])
    return textosPuros.astype(str)


# {OBSOLETE} para vetorizar o novo texto sem passar pela normalização do DF
def preprocessorNew(textNew):
    # print(df) #imprimindo o dataframe
    words = textNew.lower().split()
    stop = stopwords.words("portuguese")
    # words = ' '.join([w for w in words if not w in stop])
    return words


def dictionary(texto):
    dicionario = set()
    for lista in texto:
        dicionario.update(lista)
    return dicionario


def defineDictionaryPosition(dicionario):
    totalDePalavras = len(dicionario)
    tuplas = zip(dicionario, np.arange(totalDePalavras))
    tradutor = {palavra: indice for palavra, indice in tuplas}
    print("Total de palavras: ")
    print(totalDePalavras)
    return tradutor


# [OBSOLETE] gera a posição das palavras
def vectorize_text(text, tradutor):
    vector = [0] * len(tradutor)

    for palavra in text:
        if palavra in tradutor:
            position = tradutor[palavra]
            vector[position] += 1

    return vector


def train(texts, tradutor, marcas):
    print("Training.....")
    tvect = TfidfTransformer()  # -> Obsolete <- TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, max_df=2, lowercase=False, preprocessor=None)
    # gera a vetorização (posição das palavras) para treino e predição
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    vect_count_text = count_vect.fit_transform(texts)  # [vectorize_text(texto, tradutor) for texto in texts]
    vetoresDeTexto = tvect.fit_transform(vect_count_text)
    # Define o conjunto de dados X
    X = vetoresDeTexto  # np.array(vetoresDeTexto)
    # Define o conjunto de dados Y (labels)
    Y = np.array(marcas.tolist())
    # Define porcentagem do treino
    porcentagem_de_treino = 0.8
    # Separa o tamanho do treino a partir da porcentagem
    tamanho_do_treino = int(porcentagem_de_treino * len(Y))
    # O restante fica para a validacao
    tamanho_de_validacao = (len(Y) - tamanho_do_treino)
    # Separa os dados de treino
    treino_dados = X[0:tamanho_do_treino]
    # Separa as marcacoes de treino
    treino_marcacoes = Y[0:tamanho_do_treino]
    # Separa os dados de validacao
    validacao_dados = X[tamanho_do_treino:]
    # Separa as marcacoes de validacao
    validacao_marcacoes = Y[tamanho_do_treino:]
    print("Validacao Marcacoes: ")
    print(validacao_marcacoes)
    clf = LogisticRegression()  # MultinomialNB() obtive 62% de acerto#GaussianNB()
    clf.fit(treino_dados, treino_marcacoes)
    # accuracy
    accuracy = clf.score(validacao_dados, validacao_marcacoes)
    file_name = 'train_data.pkl'
    pickle._dump(clf, open(file_name, 'wb'))
    # fit_file = joblib.dump(clf, file_name)
    print("Indice de acerto do algoritmo: ")
    print("%.2f " % round(accuracy * 100) + "%\n")
    print("End of train...")
    predict(file_name, tvect, count_vect)
    # To get a fit_file
    # return fit_file


# to predict
def predict(fit, tvect, count_vect):
    print("\nPredict......")
    # new text to predict
    pred = ["retorno para buscar documento"]  # este deve retornar CAT Z00
    # count_vect gera as posições dos vetores de cada palavra do texto.
    new = count_vect.transform(pred)
    # X = tvect.transform(pred)  # np.array(new)
    # new_text = preprocessorNew(new)
    # carrega o modelo treinado
    loaded_model = pickle.load(open(fit, 'rb'))
    # faz a predição do novo texto de entrada
    result = loaded_model.predict(new)
    print(result)


df1 = pd.read_sql(
    "SELECT dsobservacaoclinica1, cdcatcategoria AS cat FROM iaconsultas limit 500",
    conn)
df1.columns = ['texto', 'cat']
# Grava um csv com os dados para comparações
df1.to_csv('dataframe_file.csv', sep=';', index=False)
# marca são os labels (cat) referente a cada texto
marca = df1['cat']
textosPuros = preprocessor(df1)
print("Texts...")
print(textosPuros)
# Cria um dicionário retirando as palavras repetidas 'DEPRECATE'
dict = dictionary(textosPuros)
print("Dict....")
print(dict)
# define as posições das palavras neste dicionário 'DEPRECATE'
translate = defineDictionaryPosition(dict)
# to train
train(textosPuros, translate, marca)
# TEST
# predict(textosPuros, translate, marca)
```